# Why isn't the JWT Bearer Token valid?

Tags: php, curl, jwt, header, authorization

I am trying to figure out why my code wont work.

Current codebase:

```
function initAPI(){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "URL");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "FIELDS");
    
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
 }

 $init_api_res = json_decode(initAPI());

 $access_token = $init_api_res->access_token;

 //print_r("[DEBUG] JWT: ".$access_token); //Outputting correct JWT

 function bankIdVerify() {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "URL");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = <<<DATA
    {
        //i have removed this data for safety reason also it is not relevant.
    }
    DATA;

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $resp;
 }

 print_r(bankIdVerify());
```

The result of the commented print_r are:

```
[DEBUG] JWT: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InNhbmRib3gtc2lnbmluZy1rZXktN2ViNmZkNjhiMTk5YjA0M2FlY2I1ZGRjMzI0ZWYwZmQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5zaWduaWNhdC5jb20vYXV0aC9vcGVuIiwibmJmIjoxNzA2ODc5MDEzLCJpYXQiOjE3MDY4NzkwMTMsImV4cCI6MTcwNjg3OTYxMywiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuc2lnbmljYXQuY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsic2lnbmljYXQtYXBpIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InNhbmRib3gtZ3JpdHR5LWJ1Y2tldC04MTYiLCJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiYS1zcGdlLXI5eGpUV29nbk5adlJLSzJ6bW83Iiwic2FuZGJveCI6dHJ1ZSwianRpIjoiNDYyNzg4RDlBM0VEOTMzQTZBQjhFMEI0RDExQTgzMjQifQ.picqUqyxNppiYf6NQncxE2qsWJWS7-Ls8EPhQZGbiqJIP7Rr8RUPQTdKieRxjx_A1OZj6MfR885kAYSHxFrFvsqsFdouYZ0HdeS1USXpLw9aZn9ozZOpN7O8F4wIfZDjVQ0saDNHu7QQJC9q6f5C3gtXaMxzifJ8fc2Cv69CFgiyft1fCozvmvhjxuu61ZwgL6lAbNeS5dS4df7Yc4Wmxlj-pLDhHpmuVg_mK9c4lPMKik-qp6i3MsYbSBUkPGG8lUhO4vsnfFkIjh5UnwarVShasgO6g7CcvwNpz82zjrZyHFp7gXN0H7DbX11W5Xe4QQijjDEtf7Qccoji2r-gfA
```

I am getting the error:
`{"status":401,"code":"token_invalid_not_a_jwt","title":"The provided bearer token is not a valid JWT","detail":"","traceId":"nHR4NMjtZ2lusq8bQRqNPlTF2CdQ2"}`

The JWT Token assigned to $access_token is correct and valid.

When i try to send a POST request with postman i am getting valid response. What am i doing wrong, or missing here?

Can't seem to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Where is the `$access_token` getting set ?

Comment: @shirshak007 i have updated where it's being set. Also, $access_token is returning a valid JWT as i used that result on postman, so it's valid.

Comment: have you passed the `$access_token` to the `bankIdVerify()` function?

Comment: @shirshak007 yes i have.

Comment: Try this : change this line : `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json', "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"));

Comment: @shirshak007 i have censured most of the private stuff as endpoint, and data, so i have added the "whole" codebase. also, what should i change that to?

Comment: Try this : "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"

Comment: Still "The provided bearer token is not a valid JWT". I updated it to: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/json",  "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"));